# Asynchronous Delegates in .Net Core

Tags: c#, .net-core, async-await, delegates, azure-functions

I am trying to work on performance improvement on Azure functions APIs using async calls and delegates. I got the expected results now the response it taking just 2 sec to give me a response. But behind the scenes, when I look into application insights I observed some heavy process is going on which I haven't encountered earlier while doing the Jmeter load testing before implementing delegates.

```
     public async Task Mainmethod()
    {
      Test1 test1=new Test1();
      test1.mymethod1();//trigger method. Don't wait for the output ,execute the next line and return 
                           response
     console.writeline("Request submitted successfully");
    }

public class Test1{

public Task Delgate MyDelegate();

public async Task mymethod1(){

MyDelegate myDelegate=mymethod2;

myDelegate=new myDelegate(mymethod2);
 Task.Run(() =>myDelegate.Invoke());//.Net core we dont have method for begininvoke. So, placed inside a 
                                       task to execute

}

public async Task mymethod2(){

string x=await GetAccessToken();//external call for get token (1 request --- 1 sec ; 10 request 1 sec) 

string y= await DoWork(x);//external call for get info (1 request --- 2  sec ; 10 request 14sec)
2
  Dosomemorework(y);//external call for make transaction (1 request --- 3 sec ; 10 request 26 sec)

SendEmail();//send async email

}

public Task async GetAccessToken(){

//await call for get accessToken from service provider
}

public Task async DoWork(string x){

//await call for get response from service provider
}

public Task async Dosomemorework(string y){

//await call for post information from service provider
}

public Task async SendEmail(){

await smtp.SendMailAsync(mailMessage);
}

}

My problem is, infuture when there is more load on the API. The time may increase,and possibility of timeouts.I sense some queuing mechanism is happening , or running the code on a single thread.How to overcome this.
```

Comment: Your delegate is declared to return a `Task` already - you don't need to create a task to *call* the delegate, assuming it really is asynchronous. (It would really help if you'd provide a [mcve] rather than pseudocode.)

Comment: yeah,the reason , why I intitilized Task  is "myDelegate.Invoke()" is a synchrouns call. I tried that removing Task.Run(() , but I got the same response. . I could not able to provide provide reproduible now, because I have external awaited calls

Comment: @JonSkeet you mean to say declare a delegate with "public Delgate void MyDelegate();" instead of public Delgate Task MyDelegate();

Comment: No, I'm saying that if your delegate returns a `Task` already, and assuming the implementation is effectively asynchronous, you can just invoke it directly.

Comment: Understand I tried that,but I see the same issue. The problem here is when I do a single request from postman there is no load on the APIS I can see response with in 2 sec behind the scenes I dont see long delays.When I do a load testing with 10 users I see long delays behind the scenes but however my actual response time is not changing which is 2 sec.

Comment: Unfortunately it's hard to work out what's going on when we only have pseudocode to go on, and no clear idea of what your application is doing or where you've measured the latency.